# React: How to call multiple state-changing functions, in one procedure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atomic

I have some "procedure" that i want to run, when my main component mounts:

```
  componentDidMount() {

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      this.addDummyDataForDevelopment();
    }

  }

  addDummyDataForDevelopment = () => {

    this.addItem('yoyo', "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.", true);

    this.addItem('welcome', 'heyyyy', false);        

  }
```

Each of the function calls from addDummyDataForDevelopment manipulates the state. The result of this is completely faulty:
Only one item is added(from the **second**) call.

Of course i could make addItem accommodate multiple insertions, but this is off point(what if i want to call two different functions?).

Is there a way to perform **"atomic"**(i know that Mobx supports it) actions in React, that will trigger setState only once, even though it comes from different functions, or do i just need to change my approach?

Edit: this is my addItem function:

```
 addItem = (eventName, data, owner) => {
    const id = uuid();
    const time = this.getTime();
    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, { id, eventName, time, data, owner }]
    })        
  }
```

Comment: State changes do not happen immediately: you're referencing `this.state` which hasn't changed yet; `setState` is async.

Comment: Dave: yes i'm aware of that, this is why i want to know if there's some way or design pattern in React to work around it. I mean, i can't drop the basic convention of separating my program to small functions - be it React or any other environment.

Comment: @sheff2k1 The callback method, but that said, depending on what you're *actually* doing, it might be better to just update it all at once instead of piecemeal. Can't tell from the dummy code what the actual usecase is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the callback form of `setState`:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  ...state
  items: [...state.items, { id, eventName, time, data, owner }]
})
```

This version calculates the next state based on the current state - not based on the state at the beginning of the render function which may be 'stale' - and so it's safe to do multiple updates this way.

Comment: Lol, it works. Thank you! Now i will need to understand the reason for it :D. But still, this invokes setState more than once. In a serious app this could be a performance issue. Any way around it, without dropping the small-functions idea?

Comment: @sheff2k1I don't think this is a performance issue: assuming the two `setState` calls are happening at the same time, they will still only produce a single render, which is the expensive part of changing state, anyway.